# Invalid domain in google search despite rule in webmaster tool

Tags: search, seo, google-search-console

why my domain remain without "www." in google search despite the rule in google webmaster tool. I don't understand this problem... the site is www.commissariopedemontana.it

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but here it shows-up with the www.

You might have already fixed it by now.